# How to detect Ruby hash member

Tags: ruby

The following code attempts to detect that a) `replica_2` has key `:primary` and b) `replica_1` does not have that key or has the value `true` for it. I can't detect whether a hash has a key. I'm looking for comments, corrections, etc.

```
replica_1 = { :hostname => "16.86.193.100", :port => 27017 }
replica_2 = { :hostname => "16.86.193.102", :port => 27019, :primary => true }

puts "replica_1=", replica_1

if replica_1[ :primary ] = true
  puts "replica_1[ :primary ] is set"
else
  puts "replica_1[ :primary ] is not set/true"
end

puts "replica_2=", replica_2

if replica_2[ :primary ] = true
  puts "replica_2[ :primary ] is set"
end
```

Output:

```
replica_1=
{:hostname=>"16.86.193.100", :port=>27017}
replica_1[ :primary ] is set
replica_2=
{:hostname=>"16.86.193.102", :port=>27019, :primary=>true}
replica_2[ :primary ] is set
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`= true` is setting it to `true` each time. One `=` is assignment; `==` is comparison. But it looks like you just meant:

```
if replica_2[:primary]
```

A missing key will result in `nil`.

Comment: All these answers are correct. This is kind of where I was headed though.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing two operators, `=` and `==`.

One does assignment and returns assigned value. The other compares two values and returns a boolean. You are using the former and your conditions are always true. Use this:

```
 if replica[:primary]
```

This condition will not match when `replica[:primary]` is set to `false` or `nil` or is missing.

Comment: Yup, I'm a bash guy. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Head-slap mistake, `=` -> `==` in your `if` statements and you're good.

Also, for checking for a keys presence in a hash, try `include?` or `has_key?` depending on what reads better.

Comment: Yeah, when I think Ruby, I think "scripting" which reminds me of bash and I'm trying to remember to use = instead of ==. Thanks.